# git svn keeps downloading deleted branch

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a git clone of a svn repository that does not include all of the svn commits. I have created a branch on the main SVN repository. I then did a git svn fetch to get the data of the remote branch. I did this often before. But for some reason git started getting info for this branch from commit 1. I didn't know what to do, so I deleted the branch via SVN. I then deleted the remote branch from git (using `git branch -d -r accounts@5075`). However, after doing git svn fetch, git keeps downloading the now deleted branch.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how I can fix it?

Note: I am on windows and I use Tortoise git :)

Edit [git config file]:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = url/svnroot/
    fetch = firmware/trunk/mainUnit/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = firmware/trunk/mainUnit/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = firmware/trunk/mainUnit/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
[svn]
    rmdir = true
```

Comment: $GIT_DIR/config file might be listing the deleted branches

Comment: @nullpointer The config only includes the /branches dir. No explicit branch is listed there.

Comment: could you share the config please

Comment: @nullpointer I have edited the question with my config

Comment: you might want to update `branches = firmware/trunk/mainUnit/branches/*:refs/remotes/*` which helps you fetch everything not required as well

Comment: @nullpointer To what should I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the $GIT_DIR/config file content :

```
branches = firmware/trunk/mainUnit/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
```

to

```
branches = firmware/trunk/mainUnit/branches/*:refs/remotes/<subversionbranch>/*
```

Quoting the [source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) :

> Note that git-svn keeps track of the highest revision in which a
>   branch or tag has appeared. If the subset of branches or tags is
>   changed after fetching, then $GIT_DIR/svn/.metadata must be manually
>   edited to remove (or reset) branches-maxRev and/or tags-maxRev as
>   appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for that quote! The branches-maxRev was stuck at 5075. I changed it to 5077 (commit where I deleted the SVN branch). And now fetch works like it should. Thanks!